# How to handle the hiding from LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, visibility

I have a LinearLayout in a ListView and when I click a Button i want to show or hide anything in the LinearLayout.

```
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_top_rows_layout, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
            holder.name.setText("Persönliche Daten");
            holder.morebutton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);

            holder.showOrHide = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.hideOrShow);

            View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Log.d("Debug", "1");
                    if(holder.showOrHide.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        Log.d("Debug", "2");
                        holder.showOrHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else if(holder.showOrHide.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    {
                        Log.d("Debug", "3");
                        holder.showOrHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            };
            holder.morebutton.setOnClickListener(myhandler);
```

When i set the LinearLayout to "gone" in the info_top_rows_layout.xml it dont work, but when i set it to visible, it works fine. But at the beginning i want the Layout to be "gone". I also did this in a other app and there it worked fine.

Whats wrong about that? Please help me, if you know the problem!

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wtf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/moreButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:contentDescription="@string/moreInfoButton"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hideOrShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="xxx"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And when i change it to:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hideOrShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >
```

it does not work any more. :(

Comment: Please post the appropriate XML.

Comment: when i use android:visibility="gone" > it stop working

Answer (score 0):

in your layout xml use `android:visibility="gone"`. your view will be set gone initially.

Comment: debug and check if your onclick is called

Comment: it gets called! And When i set the layout back to visible by xml-file it works how it should.

Comment: post the full xml of item .. (it seems you are changing it for list items

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked you code but i am pretty sure that your problem stands for visibility. As you can see at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) when you set the attribute `"gone"` the layout behaves like if the view had not been added.

If you set `visibility="invisible"` you still take up space for your layout and probably solve your problem.

Comment: But not visible means the space is taken and thats not what i want. :( But thank you